# Pandas consecutive dates

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
ID  Date_off    Approved
1   3/7/2018    1
1   3/8/2018    1
2   3/29/2018   1
2   3/30/2018   1
3   3/30/2018   1
4   4/2/2018    1
5   4/2/2018    1
6   4/2/2018    1
7   4/2/2018    1
8   4/2/2018    1
4   4/3/2018    1
5   4/3/2018    1
6   4/3/2018    1
7   4/3/2018    1
8   4/3/2018    1
4   4/4/2018    1
9   4/4/2018    1
5   4/4/2018    1
10  4/4/2018    1
6   4/4/2018    1
8   4/4/2018    1
9   4/5/2018    1
11  4/5/2018    1
5   4/5/2018    1
10  4/5/2018    1
6   4/5/2018    1
12  4/5/2018    1
8   4/5/2018    1
13  4/10/2018   1
14  4/10/2018   1
15  4/10/2018   1
16  4/10/2018   1
17  4/11/2018   1
13  4/11/2018   1
15  4/11/2018   1
18  4/11/2018   1
16  4/11/2018   1
15  4/12/2018   1
16  4/12/2018   1
16  4/13/2018   1
19  4/16/2018   1
19  4/17/2018   1
20  4/17/2018   1
21  4/18/2018   1
19  4/18/2018   1
20  4/18/2018   1
21  4/19/2018   1
19  4/19/2018   1
20  4/19/2018   1
22  4/20/2018   1
21  4/20/2018   1
20  4/20/2018   1
22  4/23/2018   1
23  4/23/2018   1
22  4/24/2018   1
23  4/24/2018   1
22  4/25/2018   1
23  4/25/2018   1
22  4/26/2018   1
23  4/26/2018   1
14  4/26/2018   1
22  4/27/2018   1
10  4/27/2018   1
23  4/27/2018   1
5   4/27/2018   1
14  4/27/2018   1
8   4/30/2018   1
1   4/30/2018   1
10  4/30/2018   1
23  4/30/2018   1
11  4/30/2018   1
24  4/30/2018   1
25  4/30/2018   1
14  4/30/2018   1
```

Its a list of all the days someone was on vacation. I need to group by name and return count of consecutive days someone was on vacation and first and last day.
So what I'm looking for:

```
Name   Days  From         To
Bob     2    2017-04-06   2017-04-07
Jimy    2    2017-04-07   2017-04-08
Jimy    1    2017-04-10   2017-04-10
....
```

Presently Scott's code returns this:

```
    Approved    Date_off    Date_off
    sum amin    amax
ID          
1   3   3/7/2018    4/30/2018
2   2   3/29/2018   3/30/2018
3   1   3/30/2018   3/30/2018
4   1   4/2/2018    4/2/2018
4   2   4/3/2018    4/4/2018
5   1   4/2/2018    4/2/2018
5   1   4/3/2018    4/3/2018
5   3   4/4/2018    4/27/2018
6   1   4/2/2018    4/2/2018
6   1   4/3/2018    4/3/2018
6   2   4/4/2018    4/5/2018
7   2   4/2/2018    4/3/2018
8   1   4/2/2018    4/2/2018
8   1   4/3/2018    4/3/2018
8   3   4/4/2018    4/30/2018
9   2   4/4/2018    4/5/2018
10  4   4/4/2018    4/30/2018
11  2   4/5/2018    4/30/2018
12  1   4/5/2018    4/5/2018
13  2   4/10/2018   4/11/2018
14  1   4/10/2018   4/10/2018
14  3   4/26/2018   4/30/2018
15  1   4/10/2018   4/10/2018
15  2   4/11/2018   4/12/2018
16  1   4/10/2018   4/10/2018
16  1   4/11/2018   4/11/2018
16  2   4/12/2018   4/13/2018
17  1   4/11/2018   4/11/2018
18  1   4/11/2018   4/11/2018
19  1   4/16/2018   4/16/2018
19  1   4/17/2018   4/17/2018
19  2   4/18/2018   4/19/2018
20  1   4/17/2018   4/17/2018
20  1   4/18/2018   4/18/2018
20  2   4/19/2018   4/20/2018
21  1   4/18/2018   4/18/2018
21  2   4/19/2018   4/20/2018
22  1   4/20/2018   4/20/2018
22  1   4/23/2018   4/23/2018
22  1   4/24/2018   4/24/2018
22  1   4/25/2018   4/25/2018
22  2   4/26/2018   4/27/2018
23  1   4/23/2018   4/23/2018
23  1   4/24/2018   4/24/2018
23  1   4/25/2018   4/25/2018
23  3   4/26/2018   4/30/2018
24  1   4/30/2018   4/30/2018
25  1   4/30/2018   4/30/2018
```

I only changed last line to this:

```
df.groupby(['ID','cons']).agg({'Approved':sum, 'Date_off':[np.min, np.max]}).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
```

Without min/max on date column its returning the same result. 
Maybe work days vs weekend is causing issues? This should count monday and friday as adjacent days when subtracting for adjacent days.

Comment: What about Spud should he be in the result also? And who is Jimy?  Is that Jim and Jim does have two consecutive days off.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, Jimmy should be in result two times. He was on vacation once from 04-07 to 04-08 and then later he was apsent one day (04-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated

```
df['daysdiff'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Name'])['Date'].diff()

# I modified this line 
df['cons'] = (df.sort_values('Date_off').groupby('ID')['daysdiff']
                .apply(lambda x: (x.bfill().dt.days != 1).cumsum()))

print(df.groupby(['ID','cons'])['Approved','Date_off']
        .agg({'Approved':'sum','Date_off':['min','max']})
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Approved   Date_off           
        sum        min        max
ID                               
1         2 2018-03-07 2018-03-08
1         1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
2         2 2018-03-29 2018-03-30
3         1 2018-03-30 2018-03-30
4         3 2018-04-02 2018-04-04
5         4 2018-04-02 2018-04-05
5         1 2018-04-27 2018-04-27
6         4 2018-04-02 2018-04-05
7         2 2018-04-02 2018-04-03
8         4 2018-04-02 2018-04-05
8         1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
9         2 2018-04-04 2018-04-05
10        2 2018-04-04 2018-04-05
10        1 2018-04-27 2018-04-27
10        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
11        1 2018-04-05 2018-04-05
11        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
12        1 2018-04-05 2018-04-05
13        2 2018-04-10 2018-04-11
14        1 2018-04-10 2018-04-10
14        2 2018-04-26 2018-04-27
14        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
15        3 2018-04-10 2018-04-12
16        4 2018-04-10 2018-04-13
17        1 2018-04-11 2018-04-11
18        1 2018-04-11 2018-04-11
19        4 2018-04-16 2018-04-19
20        4 2018-04-17 2018-04-20
21        3 2018-04-18 2018-04-20
22        1 2018-04-20 2018-04-20
22        5 2018-04-23 2018-04-27
23        5 2018-04-23 2018-04-27
23        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
24        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
25        1 2018-04-30 2018-04-30
```

Comment: Close, but its not that easy. Jimmy should be twice in result.

Comment: This is awesome ill just add Min date and max date to that. Thanks

Comment: When tested on full data set this is not returng accurate results, i have updated the example with full data set :(